# Swift2.3: sqlite array error with "fatal error: Index out of range"

Tags: swift, sqlite

I trying turn use sqlite to store data.

And I just chenge above function code

```
if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0 {
        let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
        let aux:AnyObject = data[indexPath.row]

        let table_recipeName = aux["recipeName"]
        cell.nameLabel.text = table_recipeName as? String

        let table_recipeType = aux["recipeType"]
        cell.typeLabel.text = table_recipeType as? String

        let table_recipeImage = aux["recipeImage"]
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: table_recipeImage as! String)

        let table_recipeIsFavor = aux["recipeIsFavor"]
        cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor

        let table_recipeUserPhoto = aux["recipeUserPhoto"]
         cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: table_recipeUserPhoto as! String)

        let table_recipeUserName = aux["recipeUserName"]
        cell.userName.text = table_recipeUserName as? String


    }
```

and the sqlite function is here

```
 //**********************SQLite********************************//
var statement = COpaquePointer()
var data: [[String: AnyObject]] = []

func loadData() {
    let db_path = "/Users/huangpinquan/Desktop/Recipes/Recipes/Recipes.sqlite"
    var db = COpaquePointer()

    let status = sqlite3_open(db_path,&db)
    if (status == SQLITE_OK) {
        print("Open the sqlite success!\n")
    }else {
        print("Open the sqlite failed!\n")
    }

    let query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE type:'麵食' "
    //let query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM recipe"
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db , query_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //self.data.removeAllObjects()
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            var recipeArray: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

            let recipeName = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
            let recipe_name = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(recipeName)) ?? ""

            let recipeType = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)
            //....just like "statement, 0"

            let recipeImage = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)
            //....

            let recipeIsFavor = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3)
            //....

            let recipeUserPhoto = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)
            //....

            let recipeUserName = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)
            //....

            recipeArray["recipeName"] = recipe_name
            recipeArray["recipeType"] = recipe_type
            recipeArray["recipeImage"] = recipe_image
            recipeArray["recipIsFavor"] = recipe_isFavor
            recipeArray["recipeUserPhoto"] = recipe_userPhoto
            recipeArray["recipeUserName"] = recipe_userName

            data.append(recipeArray)
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }else {
        print("read the sqlite data failed")
    }

}
```

when the code like this in the "func loadData"

```
let query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE type:'麵食' "
```

it will cause a error

> fatal error: Index out of range

but if code like this, it doesn't have any error

```
let query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM recipe"
```

[http://imgur.com/a/x3lr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn3iX.png)

It's my whole code, if you want.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/79eb4b2506889929cfe92dfcab3731c4

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Where do you get this error? On which line?

Comment: FYI - Never use `SELECT * ...`. Explicitly list out the columns you wish to select.

Comment: The error  is on the line "let aux:AnyObject = data[indexPath.row]"

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing where you get your error, I wonder if your statement compiles. I'm no SQL expert, but `"WHERE type:'...'"` looks suspicious. First, you later call this field `recipeType` and second, you probably want `"WHERE recipeType='string literal'"`, no?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/20mko but, the instruction in the SQLite doesn't have any  problem, why it's error in swift?

Comment: I don't know: you're not providing much information. If you add a breakpoint at the error line, what is the state of the data object (what's its count) and what's the value of indexPath.row?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/79eb4b2506889929cfe92dfcab3731c4 here  is my code

Comment: I'm not swinging a hammer for a carpenter. I'm not giving myself a rectal examination for a doctor, and I'm not running the debugger for you. Learn to use the tools of your trade.